# geom_ribbon does not follow the order of my vector (ggplot)

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a pressure distribution from an airfoil with some confidence bounds at each point. Hence, I was trying to implement the `geom_ribbon` function to create continuous shaded bounds. A simple example should go like this:

```
x = c(1, .8, .6, .4, .2, 0, .1,.3,.5,.7,.9)
y = c(-10,-10,-15,-20,-100,-400,10000,6000,800,300,80)
ymax = y*1.1
ymin = y*.9
df = data.frame(x,y)
mdf = melt(df, id.vars="x")
ggplot() + 
geom_path(data=mdf, aes(x=x, y=value)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
```

The problem is that the `geom_ribbon` function does not follow the original order of my vector when plotting, but it re-orders everything in ascending manner such as `geom_line` does. I would like to use `geom_ribbon` in the same manner as `geom_path`, but I cannot find a command to make it work in such way.

Comment: Any reproducible example? Because this question is going to be closed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Pascal. I have just edited the question to make it more clear. I hope this can clarify better the goal